# Сравнение двух списков на нахождение элементов которые соответствуют правилам

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, list

Вопрос заключается в том, что например у меня есть два списка:

```
lst1 = ['1', '2' , '3' , '4']
lst2 = ['123', '234' , '345' , '334']
```

Как мне найти такие элементы во втором списке, которые включают в себя только те элементы, которые есть в первом, но, если в первом списке есть одна единица, то например элемент "112" с второго списка не подходит.

Tо есть результатом программы должен быть

```
ls3 = ['123', '234']
```

'345' - не подошло потому что там есть элемент "5" которого нет в первом списке

'334' - не подошло потому что там есть два элемента "3", а в первом списке элемент "3" есть только один

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Check if two unordered lists are equal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9623114/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если известно как определить, можно ли составить строку `word` из заданных символов `chars`, используя каждый символ в `chars` *не более* его числа повторений (известен `can_build(word, chars)` предикат), то задача сводится к:

```
result = list(filter(can_build, lst2))
```

или более читаемо:

```
result = [word for word in lst2 if can_build(word)]
```

где `can_build` использует `chars = lst1` внутри.

Если бы требовалось использовать *все* символы из `chars`, тогда это была бы проверка является ли `word` анаграммой `chars`, к примеру: *"просветитель"* можно получить перестановкой букв *"терпеливость"*. Можно использовать [похожие решения](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96475/6143), когда точное равенство заменено на "не более".

`can_build()` можно реализовать, найдя является ли `word` [мультимножество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) подмножеством `chars` мультимножества. Если бы все символы в `chars` и `word` были уникальны, то

```
can_build = set("1234").issuperset
```

`collections.Counter` реализует идею множества, в котором элементы могут повторяться, то есть [мультимножества](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE). Как показано в элегантном решении в [ответе @Timofey Bondarev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/590235/23044), эту коллекцию можно использовать чтобы реализовать `can_build`:

```
can_build = lambda word, chars=Counter(lst1): not (Counter(word) - chars)
```

Можно реализовать тот же алгоритм вручную, не используя `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def Counter(letters):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for letter in letters:
        counts[letter] += 1
    return counts

chars_count = Counter(chars)

def can_build(word):
    return all(chars_count[char] >= count for char, count in Counter(word).items())
```

Можно использовать простой список, если все символы принадлежат какому-либо алфавиту, тогда так как `chars` всё время один и тот же, то можно закэшировать `chars.count` значения. Например, если `chars` может содержать только цифры `0-9`:

```
from string import digits

chars_count = [(digit, chars.count(digit)) for digit in digits]

def can_build(word):
    return all(word.count(digit) <= count for digit, count in chars_count)
```

это `O(N * M)` решение (`M=len(digits)`—размер алфавита), в отличии от `O(N)` решения, использующего `Counter()`. Если алфавит нефиксированный: `alphabet = set(word)`, тогда это `O(N**2)` (квадратичный) алгоритм. Если `alphabet` фиксированный как в примере, то это `O(N)` (линейное) решение. Для небольшого алфавита, например, для boolean цифр (`alphabet=(0,1)`) или ДНК-строк (`alphabet="GTAC"`), [это решение могло быть даже быстрее решения с `Counter()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14186533/4279).

Ещё пример применения: если `word`, `chars` это числа, представленные их простыми множителями (например: `(2,2,3)` представляет `12`, `(5,7)` представляет `35`), тогда `can_build()` отвечает на вопрос является ли `word` делителем `chars`, то есть верно ли что: `chars % word == 0`.

> ***Q:*** как реализовать код, если избавиться от условия о том, что элемент должен повторяться столько раз сколько его есть в первом списке???

Уже ответ в этом предположении работает. Иначе это был бы случай с анаграммами: количество повторений совпадает. Решения с `Counter()` и с `<=`, `>=` НЕ требуют, чтобы элемент повторялся *"столько раз сколько его есть в первом списке"* (можно меньше).

Если вы имеете ввиду, что количество повторений вообще не важно, а интересует только есть  элемент или нет, то ситуация аналогична случаю когда все элементы уникальны, то есть:

```
can_build = set(lst1).issuperset
```

как уже упомянуто выше.

Comment: Я сегодня прочитал ваш ответ, и он действительно очень хорошо обясняе всю суть поставленной задачи. Спасибо вам за это. Но мне стало интересно, как реализовать код, если избавиться от  условия о том, что элемент должен повторяться столько раз сколько его есть в первом списке ???

Comment: @Bernard: обновил ответ

Comment: Што такое issuperset ???

Comment: @Bernard в частности `set(chars).issuperset(word)` говорит "*можно ли составить строку word из заданных символов chars*"—это метод стандартного класса set.

Comment: Но issuperset возращает True или False , а как вернуть список елементов ( word ) коториэ можно создать из заданных символов ( char )

Comment: @Bernard issuperset можно использовать чтобы can_build предикат определить (как явно показано в ответе). Затем можно использовать can_build функцию, чтобы найти уже  результат—посмотрите на первые два примера кода в ответе.

Answer (score 10):

Эту проблему можно решить, используя стандартный класс для мультимножества `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

lst1 = ['1', '2' , '3' , '4']
lst2 = ['123', '234' , '345' , '334']

base = Counter(lst1)
result = [s for s in lst2 if not (Counter(s) - base)]
```

Условие `not (Counter(s) - base)` проверяет то, что в мультимножестве `s` не больше элементов, чем в `base`

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, но мне еще не приходилось работать с 'Counter' поэтому, если вам не трудно можно поподробнее рассказать, что делают две последние строчки .

Comment: Counter подсчитывает сколько раз встречается каждое значение из списка, который вы передали его конструктору.

Comment: @Bernard: `not container` является истиной для пустых контейнеров в Питоне. При вычитании из `Counter()` в результате остаются только элементы с *положительным* счётом. В итоге, если разница не пуста, то элемент из второго списка содержит цифры, которых нет в первом списке.

Answer (score 5):

```
[l2 for l2 in lst2 if all(l2.count(l) <= lst1.count(l) for l in set(l2))]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
lst1 = ['1', '2' , '3' , '4']
lst2 = ['123', '234' , '345' , '334']
S1 = set(lst1)
S2 = set(lst2)
S3 = set()
for x in S2:
    if set(x) <= S1: S3.add(x)
lst3 = list(S3)
for x in lst3:
    for y in x:
        if x.count(y) > 1:
            count = lst3.index(x)
            continue
lst3.pop(count)
print(lst3)
```

Если просто по логике вещей, без особых премудростей. Чуток знать о множествах (из школы), циклы и списки. Ответ ['123', '234']

Comment: Стандартное множество `set` в питоне может содержать в себе только уникальные элементы, поэтому для другого набора `lst1` (с повторяющимися элементами), использование `set` приведет к неправильному решению.

Comment: Хотите что-то сказать - напишите код.. Я привел работоспособный код. А вы просто говорите слова. И как известно (и стало уже классикой жанра - "Болтовня ничего не стоит. Покажите мне код.
— Linus Torvalds".

Comment: От того, покажу я код или нет, поведение стандартного множества в `python` не изменится, увы. Просвещайтесь [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: совершенно беспредметный разговор. Я у вас ничего не спрашивал вроде. Я не о поведении множества, а про ваши разговоры.

Comment: Вроде для того, чтобы комментировать, не нужно ничего спрашивать. Вы попробуйте задать `lst1 = [1,2,3,3,4]` или `lst1=[1,2,3,3]` и расскажете потом, какой у вас "работоспособный" код.

Comment: Если вы умеете читать, то увидите, что вопрос выглядел так:Вопрос заключается в том, что например у меня есть два списка:

lst1 = ['1', '2' , '3' , '4']
lst2 = ['123', '234' , '345' , '334'] будет другой вопрос, будет другой ответ. Зачем вы меня комментируете? Я ничего не спрашивал у вас. Не занимайтесь графоманией.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49963/discussion-between-dio4-and-nikmoon).

Answer (score 0):

Решение выше, конечно более коротко, но по человечески можно сделать так:

```
список = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
список2 = ['123', '234', '345', '34']

результат = []
for сочетание in список2:
    временный_список = список[:]  # копия списка
    for цифра in сочетание:
        if цифра in временный_список:
            временный_список.remove(цифра)  # чтобы не более одной проверки на число
        else:
            break
    else: результат.append(сочетание)

print(результат)


===================== RESTART: C:\Python 3.5\задачка.py =====================
['123', '234', '34']
```