# Как найти элементы во втором списке состоящие из элементов первого?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например :

```
lst1 = ['1', '2', '3']
lst2 = ['123', '1112' , '134']
```

Результат будет :

```
['123', '1112']
```

Comment: Может вам всё-таки почитать какой-нибудь самоучитель для чайников по питону? А то у вас куча однотипных вопросов на знание самых основ. Здесь такое не приветствуется.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Сравнение двух списков на нахождение элементов которые соответствуют правилам](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590198/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы узнать присутствуют ли все символы слова в заданном наборе, можно использовать [`set.issuperset()` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issuperset), который говорит можно ли составить слово (элемент в `lst2`) из заданных символов (список `lst1`) без учёта повторений:

```
>>> chars = {'1', '2', '3'}
>>> can_build = chars.issuperset
>>> can_build('123')
True
>>> can_build('1112')
True
>>> can_build('134')
False
```

Или для ввода в вопросе:

```
print(*filter(set(lst1).issuperset, lst2))
# -> 123 1112
```

Чтобы список получить, как я [явно показал в ответе к предыдущему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591061/23044):

```
result = list(filter(can_build, lst2))
```

Или:

```
result = [word for word in lst2 if can_build(word)]
```

Answer (score 3):

я бы сделал так:

```
In [150]: [s for s in lst2 if not (set(s) - set(lst1))]
Out[150]: ['123', '1112']
```

логика:

```
In [151]: [set(s) - set(lst1) for s in lst2]
Out[151]: [set(), set(), {'4'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[s for s in lst2 if all(a in lst1 for a in s)]
```

Comment: вместо `all(a in lst1 for a in s)` (`O(m*k*n)` алгоритм), [можно `set(lst1).issuperset(s)` использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592978/23044) (`O(n+m*k)` алгоритм). Конструкцию набора (`set(lst1)`) можно из цикла вынести. Хотя для крошечных коллекций как в примере в вопросе это не играет роли.