# Подбор массивов по содержимому целевого массива

Tags: python

Вопрос заключается в том, что например у меня есть целевой массив наименований и количества:

```
target_array = [['n1', 30], ['n2', 10], ['n3', 34], ['n4', 25], ..., ['n100', 43]]
```

и набор массивов, содержимое которых удовлетворяет лишь части содержимого целевого массива (как по наименованиям так и по количеству):

```
array1 = [[['n1', 2], ['n2', 3], ..., ['n50', 10]]
array2 = [[['n3', 22], ['n4', 2], ..., ['n70', 5]]
...
array30 = [[['n2', 5], ['n4', 9], ..., ['n99', 8]]
```

Цель - подобрать такую комбинацию массивов `array1...array30` и с такой кратностью, чтобы разница [мультимножества](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) суммы произведений подобранных массивов `{(array1*x1)+(array2*x2)+...+(array30*x30)}` и мультимножества целевого массива `{target_array}` была минимальной:

```
`({(array1*x1)+(array2*x2)+...+(array30*x30)} - {target_array}) -> min`
```

Для тех, кому интересно, у данной задачи есть вполне прикладное применение при планировании заданий в лазерную резку, а именно: по заказу `(target_array)` формировать такой набор карт раскроя и их количеств в резку `((array1*x1)+(array2*x2)+...+(array30*x30))`, чтобы минимизировать общее время на выполнение заказа.

Как видно из условий, в задаче преследуются три цели:

1. охватить все наименования
2. охватить все количество
3. минимизировать остатки

Очень хочется решить задачу, однако пока вопросов больше, чем найденных ответов. Например, формат данных в обработке (пока искал среди множеств, но там не учитывается кратность), метод обработки данных (пока на ум приходит грубый перебор, хотя уверен, есть куда более эффективный метод). К сожалению, пока мои знания как в Python так и в комбинаторике крайне слабые, потому прошу не рубить с плеча, а по возможности посоветовать, куда копать.

Comment: скорее всего надо копать в сторону более полной модели прикладного процесса или объекта.
По тому что есть  -  ну точно не множество, если надо с повторениями. Или самому реализовывать класс "мультимножества".
Хотя класс Counter() порою используют для этого
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590198/Сравнение-двух-списков-на-нахождение-элементов-которые-соответствуют-правилам

Comment: посмотрите также модуль itertools чтоб не изобретать велосипед в комбинаторике https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools

Comment: как успехи? удалось решить?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, это решается аналитически, как линейная комбинация векторов, где `array1...array30` — вектора, `x1...x30` — коэффициент лямбда, а `target_array` — это x:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Найти коэффициенты можно [методом Гаусса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150851/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-3) (недостающие ячейки каждого вектора `array` заполняются нулями)