# метод гаусса на python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Мне необходимо выполнить задачу: Метод Гаусса на питоне. Собственно сам алгоритм я реализовал, там ничего сложного, вот он:

```
myA=[
 [1.0, -2.0, 3.0, -4.0],
 [3.0, 3.0, -5.0, -1.0],
 [3.0, 0.0, 3.0, -10.0],
 [-2.0, 1.0, 2.0, -3.0]
]

myB = [
 2.0,
 -3.0,
 8.0,
 5.0]
# --- end of исходные данные

# --- вывод системы на экран
def FancyPrint(A, B, selected):
    for row in range(len(B)):
        print("(", end='')
        for col in range(len(A[row])):
             print("\t{1:10.2f}{0}".format(" " if (selected is None
or selected != (row, col)) else "*", A[row][col]), end='')
        print("\t) * (\tX{0}) = (\t{1:10.2f})".format(row + 1, B[row]))
# --- end of вывод системы на экран

# --- перемена местами двух строк системы
def SwapRows(A, B, row1, row2):
    A[row1], A[row2] = A[row2], A[row1]
    B[row1], B[row2] = B[row2], B[row1]
# --- end of перемена местами двух строк системы

# --- деление строки системы на число
def DivideRow(A, B, row, divider):
    A[row] = [a / divider for a in A[row]]
    B[row] /= divider
# --- end of деление строки системы на число

# --- сложение строки системы с другой строкой, умноженной на число
def CombineRows(A, B, row, source_row, weight):
    A[row] = [(a + k * weight) for a, k in zip(A[row], A[source_row])]
    B[row] += B[source_row] * weight
# --- end of сложение строки системы с другой строкой, умноженной начисло

# --- решение системы методом Гаусса (приведением к треугольному виду)
def Gauss(A, B):
    column = 0
    while (column < len(B)):
        print("Ищем максимальный по модулю элемент в {0}-м столбце:".format(column + 1))
        current_row = None
        for r in range(column, len(A)):
            if current_row is None or abs(A[r][column]) > abs(A[current_row][column]):
                 current_row = r
        if current_row is None:
            print("решений нет")
            return None
        FancyPrint(A, B, (current_row, column))
        if current_row != column:
            print("Переставляем строку с найденным элементом повыше:")
            SwapRows(A, B, current_row, column)
            FancyPrint(A, B, (column, column))
        print("Нормализуем строку с найденным элементом:")
        DivideRow(A, B, column, A[column][column])
        FancyPrint(A, B, (column, column))
        print("Обрабатываем нижележащие строки:")
        for r in range(column + 1, len(A)):
            CombineRows(A, B, r, column, -A[r][column])
        FancyPrint(A, B, (column, column))
        column += 1
    print("Матрица приведена к треугольному виду, считаем решение")
    X = [0 for b in B]
    for i in range(len(B) - 1, -1, -1):
        X[i] = B[i] - sum(x * a for x, a in zip(X[(i + 1):], A[i][(i + 1):]))
    print("Получили ответ:")
    print("\n".join("X{0} =\t{1:10.2f}".format(i + 1, x) for i, x in
enumerate(X)))
    return X
# --- end of решение системы методом Гаусса (приведением к треугольному виду)
print("Исходная система:")
FancyPrint(myA, myB, None)
print("Решаем:")
Gauss(myA, myB)
```

Но мне необходимо, чтобы матрицу коэффицентов и правых частей можно было вводить в самой программе, а не в коде. То есть чтобы появилось поле "Введите матрицу коэфицентов" и "Введите матрицу правых частей", я ввожу туда данные и программа вычисляет.
Пробовал изменить первые две строки на

```
myA = input("введите матрицу коэфициентов")
myB= input("Введите матрицу правых частей")
```

Но выдает ошибку
Не подскажите как можно исправить? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так (для матрицы `myA`):

```
my_A_rows = int(input("введите число строк матрицы коэфициентов: "))
    
print("введите матрицу коэфициентов (по строках, пробелы между коэффициентами")
myA = [list(map(float, (input(f"строка {i+1}: ").split()))) 
            for i in range(my_A_rows) ]
```

---

Тест:

> ```
> введите число строк матрицы коэфициентов: 2
> введите матрицу коэфициентов (по строках, пробелы между коэффициентами
> строка 0: 1 2 3
> строка 1: 4 5 6
>
> In[91]: myA
> Out[91]: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
> ```

---

Для матрицы `myB`:

```
myB = map(float, input("Введите матрицу правых частей, пробелы между числами: ").split())
myB = list(myB)
```

Comment: Работает. Но тогда выдает такую ошибку:

Comment: `IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-48aa536e553b> in <module>
     74 # --- end of решение системы методом Гаусса (приведением к треугольному виду)
     75 print("Исходная система:")
---> 76 FancyPrint(myA, myB, None)
     77 print("Решаем:")
     78 Gauss(myA, myB)`

Comment: `<ipython-input-11-48aa536e553b> in FancyPrint(A, B, selected)
     15     for row in range(len(B)):
     16         print("(", end='')
---> 17         for col in range(len(A[row])):
     18              print("\t{1:10.2f}{0}".format(" " if (selected is None
     19 or selected != (row, col)) else "*", A[row][col]), end='')

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Эта ошибка не имеет ни какой связи с методом ввода матриц (прямо или через `input()` - пока вы ввели для всякой строки одинаковое число коэффициентов). — Лучше всего будет для этого задать  другой вопрос с просьбой об отладку.

Comment: а все работает. Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 2):

можно с помощью генерации списков:

```
n = 3

print('введите матрицу коэффициентов')
A = [[int(elem) for elem in input().split()] for i in range(n)]
print(A)

print('введите вектор')
b = [int(elem) for elem in input().split()]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет такого?

```
myA=[0]
myB=[0]
strok=int(input('Введите количество строк: '))
kolom=int(input('Введите количество столбцов: '))
myA=[[0]*kolom]*strok
for s in range(strok):
    for k in range(kolom):
        myA[s][k]=float(input('Введите значения коэффициентов: '))  
myB=[[0]]*strok
for s in range(strok):
    myB[s]=float(input('Введите значения правых частей: '))
```